# Logging users in programatically using their credentials - best practises?

Tags: android, authentication, mobile, passwords

I'm building an application on mobile platform. My app makes use of an existing service (let's call it service A) and it's data. I'm planning to use some of the user profile information that's only available when the user is logged in to that platform.
Logging an user into that platform programmatically is straight forward and not a problem at all. Upon logging the user in, the response includes a jwt token which can be used to authenticate further requests.

To summarize:

- My app makes use of a third party service and their data
- In order to get the data, I need the user to enter their credentials in order to start making authed requests
- Asking for credentials seems bad and users don't probably want to enter their details into my non-official app

Here are my concerns. My application is not an official representation of service A and asking users to provide their username and password in order to make requests on their behalf seems bad. Are there any best practises on this topic? Is it a no-go solution from the beginning? Are there any legal implications that I would have to consider since the credentials belong to the user (combined with service A)?

Thanks!

Edit: My mobile app **wouldn't store** the username or password anywhere.

Comment: I guess it all depends on your "service A" capabilities. Check how Facebook, Twitter does it (probably scenario when their native app is not installed)

Comment: The service A doesn't offer any special authentication methods for devs. I would use the same login mechanism as they have for normal login (as you would login to their service normally).